# memory usage in windows vs Linux

Tags: linux, windows, memory

I ran the same C program and Perl program and Ada program on Windows 8 and Red Hat Linux 5.2. The programs are using twice as much memory on the windows system.  Any ideas why? Sorry it is a huge/private program and I am not allowed to post the program. thank you

Answer (score 4):

It could be a number of reasons. In general, Linux systems have a smaller memory footprint than Windows machines. Although the code in your program may be the same in both systems, the way each OS completes the tasks listed in your program will be different. This is due to the fact that Linux and Windows have a different kernel so that even though the result is the same the means of achieving the result have little in common.